# When using paperclip on Rails3, the some characters( @ and ~)  get erased or altered from the file name when uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I'm not sure if this is a paperclip issue. Tried it on gitlab and the same thing happened.

I have a back end for an iOS app written in Rails, and when I upload an image file with the @ character in the filename, it gets erased upon uploading, if I have a file named,

```
aaa@2x.jpg
```

it gets saved as

```
aaa2x.jpg
```

Also, ~ gets converted into a _.

This is a problem because iOS apps presume that retina supported images are named with the @2x prefix.

I can regex the file name post upload and change it in the database and rename the file, but that seems like an odd hack to do, anyone have any idea whats happening? How to have the file name saved properly to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus, you should be able to use any character, including NUL in file names. But OS APIs may limit some characters for legacy reasons.

It can be server or client issue, try to debug your application and check file name provided in `request.request_parameters` it should contain valid file name.

If you going to use uploaded files in URLs you should transliterate them before upload, this also resolve your problem. To do this you can use this extension:

```
module TransliteratePaperclip
   def transliterate_file_name(paperclip_file)
    paperclip_file=[paperclip_file] unless paperclip_file.is_a?(Enumerable)
    paperclip_file.each do |file|
      filename=read_attribute("#{file}_file_name")
      if filename.present?
        extension = File.extname(filename).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
        filename = filename.gsub(/\.#{extension}$/, '')
        self.send(file).instance_write(:file_name, "#{filename.parameterize}.#{extension.parameterize}")
      end
    end
  end
end

 # include the extension 
 ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, TransliteratePaperclip)
```

put this code in `/config/initializers/paperclip_transliterate.rb` and in your paperclip model:

```
before_post_process { |c| transliterate_file_name(:file) }
```

where `:file` is attribute defined by `has_attached_file`.